# looping through dates to produce a file

Tags: python, bash

I have two date values (can be any date)

```
start_dt='2019-07-20 00:01'
end_dt='2019-07-24 23:59'
```

Need to produce a file with below rows

Number of rows = (end_dt - start_dt) is 5

start_sequence has to be incremented by 50

```
start_date|end_date|start_sequence
2019-07-20 00:01|2019-07-24 23:59|0
2019-07-20 00:01|2019-07-24 23:59|50
2019-07-20 00:01|2019-07-24 23:59|100
2019-07-20 00:01|2019-07-24 23:59|150
2019-07-20 00:01|2019-07-24 23:59|200
```

Thank you for helping , below is the final working code on my Python 2.7

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
start_dt = datetime.strptime('2019-07-20 00:01', dt_fmt)
end_dt = datetime.strptime('2019-07-24 23:59', dt_fmt)
num_rows = (end_dt - start_dt)

num_rows += timedelta(hours=1)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    headers = ['start_date','end_date','start_sequence']
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for i in range(0, num_rows.days*50, 50):
        row = []
        row.append(start_dt)
        row.append(end_dt)
        row.append(i)
        writer.writerow(row)
    f.close()
```

Comment: And what have you tried? are you working on `pandas` or any data-related libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `datetime` objects and want to write plain text file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%S"
start_dt = datetime.strptime('2019-07-20 00:01', dt_fmt)
end_dt = datetime.strptime('2019-07-24 23:59', dt_fmt)
num_rows = (end_dt - start_dt)
```

The num_rows.days in your case will be 4. if you want it to be 5 you may have to write rounding algorithm as per your need. something like this might work in your case.

```
num_rows += timedelta(hours=1)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("start_date|end_date|start_sequence\n")
    for i in range(0, num_rows.days*50, 50):
        f.write(f"{start_dt}|{end_dt}|{i}\n")
```

Out:

```
start_date|end_date|start_sequence
2019-07-20 00:00:01|2019-07-24 23:00:59|0
2019-07-20 00:00:01|2019-07-24 23:00:59|50
2019-07-20 00:00:01|2019-07-24 23:00:59|100
2019-07-20 00:00:01|2019-07-24 23:00:59|150
2019-07-20 00:00:01|2019-07-24 23:00:59|200
```

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
start_dt='2019-07-20 00:01'
end_dt='2019-07-24 23:59'
start_epoch=`date -d "${start_dt}" +%s`
end_epoch=`date -d "${end_dt}" +%s`
start_sequence=0
for i in `seq 1 $(( (${end_epoch} - ${start_epoch}) / 86400 + 1 ))`
do
    echo "${start_dt}|${end_dt}|${start_sequence}"
    start_sequence=$(( start_sequence + 50 ))
done
```